# 行列をdatファイルに保存する関数について

Tags: c

下記のような初期化した行列と列ベクトルをdatファイルに保存するプログラムを描いたのですが、実際にこのコードを実行しても機能してくれません。ですがなぜか

```c
init(m * n, 1, A);
```

の前に

```c
printf("%d", m);
```

と入れるとうまく機能します。これは何故なのでしょうか？[image: 上から2行が失敗例で最後が成功例です。]

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
void init(int n, float x, float * o) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        o[i] = x;
    }
}

void print(int m, int n, const float * x) {
    for(int i = 0; i < m ; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            printf("%.4f ", x[j + i * n]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void save(const char *filename, int m, int n, const float *A, const float*b){

    FILE *fp;
    if((fp = fopen(filename,"wb"))==NULL){
        printf("\aファイルをオープンできません。\n");
    } else {
        fwrite(A, sizeof(float), m * n, fp);
        fwrite(b, sizeof(float), n, fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;
    float *A = malloc( sizeof(float) * (m*n));
    float *b = malloc( sizeof(float) * n);
    m = atoi(argv[1]);
    n = atoi(argv[2]);

    init(m * n, 1, A);
    init(n, 2, b);
    print(m, n, A);
    print(1, n, b);
    save("test.dat", m, n, A, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `m` と `n` が初期値(`0`)のままでメモリアロケート(`malloc()`)していますね。`m = atoi(argv[1])`, `n = atoi(argv[2])` を実行してから `malloc()` を行うのではないでしょうか。

Comment: たしかに…
初歩的なミスでした…ありがとうございます！
メモリに関する知識が少ないのでイマイチよく理解できてないのですが、printfをすることでメモリが確保されて動くようになった、という考え方で良いのでしょうか？

Comment: **_printfをすることでメモリが確保されて動くようになった、という考え方で良いのでしょうか？_** 良くありません。`printf("%d", m);`で、`A`, `b`に必要なメモリが割り当てられることはありません。メモリに関するエラーの怖いところは、ちょっとした条件の変化で「たまたま動いているように見える」ことがあることです。`printf("%d", m);`のような1行が挟まることによって、実行時の変数やポインタの位置がほんのちょっとずれることで、すぐにはクラッシュしない、なんてことも起こり得ます。そんな「たまたま」に依存したり、解決法と勘違いしたりしないようにして下さい。

Comment: 丁寧な解答ありがとうございます。しっかりと細かいところまでチェックして行くようにします。